# Django: set birthday just by giving the month and day

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm totally new in Django

I want to make a field in Admin panel, that we could set the birthday of a user just by giving the month and day. Right now, we can only give the date, but that's not what I want. I want for example 2 dropdowns one for the day and one for the month

[image]

My User model looks like that

Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):

    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.get_full_name()}'
```

Comment: Just use charField and integerField and render these in `Select` widgets, then you can use the `datetime` library to make a datetime object out of it

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve this problem with **`DateField()`** as per your requirement

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

#### admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
import datetime

class ProfileAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday_month = forms.IntegerField(label='Birthday Month', widget=forms.Select(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 13)]))
    birthday_day = forms.IntegerField(label='Birthday Day', widget=forms.Select(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 32)]))
    birthday_year = forms.IntegerField(label='Birthday Year', widget=forms.Select(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(datetime.datetime.now().year - 200, datetime.datetime.now().year)]))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'birthday_month', 'birthday_day', 'birthday_year']

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProfileAdminForm
    list_display = ['user', 'birthday']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        month = form.cleaned_data['birthday_month']
        day = form.cleaned_data['birthday_day']
        year = form.cleaned_data['birthday_year']

        # Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD
        obj.birthday = f'{year:04d}-{month:02d}-{day:02d}'
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

#### Browser Preview

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to not show the birthday YEAR in Birthday?

Comment: answer updated pl check